# Log4j2 - one logger overrides another logger's message

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

We are trying to migrate our application from slf4j with log4j to log4j2 (2.10.0).
We noticed a problem:

1) We call

```
LOGGER.warn("Message: object value is {}", object)
```

from class A

2) Object overrides `toString` method invoking static method from other class B

3) Method that generates String representation of object use logger :

```
LOGGER.warn( "Used ObjectsToStringGenerator for class: {}", o.getClass() )
```

We expect logs to looks like:

```
2018-02-05 06:07:25.233 [main] WARN MainClass - Message: object values is [object string]
2018-02-05 06:07:25.233 [main] WARN ExampleObject - Used ObjectsToStringGenerator for class: class ExampleObject
```

But we get this:

```
2018-02-05 15:01:43.359 [main] WARN MainClass - Used ObjectsToStringGenerator for class: class ExampleObject[object string]
2018-02-05 15:01:43.373 [main] WARN ObjectsToStringGenerator - ObjectsToStringGenerator for class: ExampleObject
```

If we explicity invoke `toString` method:

```
LOGGER.warn("Message: object value is {}", object.toString() )
```

everything is working as expected, but of course, we would like to avoid explicite use of `object.toString()`. 
We tried also using sync loggers/appendrs but we got error:

```
main ERROR Recursive call to appender CONSOLE.
```

Below example code/logger configuration:

MainClass.java:

```
public class MainClass
{
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger( MainClass.class );

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    //...

    LOGGER.warn( "Message: object value is {}", new ExampleObject() );

    //...
  }
}
```

ExampleObject.java:

```
public class ExampleObject
{
  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return ObjectsToStringGenerator.getStringValue( this );
  }

}
```

ObjectsToStringGenerator.java:

```
public class ObjectsToStringGenerator
{
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger( ObjectsToStringGenerator.class );

  public static String getStringValue(Object o){
    LOGGER.warn( "Used ObjectsToStringGenerator for class: {}", o.getClass() );
    return "[object string]";
  }
}
```

The configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %p %c{2} - %m%n" />
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>


    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
    </Root>

  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Are you testing this in `Console` appender?

Comment: I tested this also in RollingFile appender and our simple impementation with the same result.